# Close icon is missing for all windows

Tags: 18.04, icons, desktop-icons

I tried out [regolith](https://regolith-linux.org/), which gives a separate login DE. However, when switching back to the regular Ubuntu login, the close icon on all windows is missing, and the minimize and maximize icons are more like outlines rather than icons.[image]

Any ideas on how I can restore the icons?

I'm on 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **dconf Editor** application (`dconf-editor` from command line) and go to:

```
/ org / gnome / desktop / wm / preferences / button-layout
```

Edit the **Custom value** as follows:

```
appmenu:minimize,maximize,close
```

Click the **Apply** button.

After that you should have the three usual buttons.

Note: If you do not have the **dconf Editor** application, you can install it using:

```
$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
```